# Getting metrics data of two servers using Amazon Cloudwatch

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I am writing a java code for retrieving `Amazon EC2 metrics` data using `Amazon Cloudwatch`. Below is the sample code which is working fine.

```
    Dimension instanceDimension = new Dimension();
    instanceDimension.setName("InstanceId);
    instanceDimension.setValue(instanceId);

   GetMetricStatisticsRequest request = new GetMetricStatisticsRequest().withStartTime(startTime)
                                                .withNamespace("AWS/EC2")
                                                .withPeriod(60 * 5)
                                                .withDimensions(instanceDimension)
                                                .withMetricName("CPUUtilization")
                                                .withStatistics("Average")
                                                .withEndTime(endTime);

    GetMetricStatisticsResult getMetricStatisticsResult = cloudWatch.getMetricStatistics(request);
```

In the above code, I am passing one server's instance id. I need to get the metrics data of two servers having different instance id. So, my query is can i do it in a single call by specifying two dimensions as list and pass it to `withDimensions` OR do i need to make two different calls altogether to get the metrics data of two servers?

Answer (score 0):

It's a common question. You need to make two separate requests for each entity, combining multiple instances in one request is not currently supported by the CloudWatch API.